# particular auto-format for Properties C# VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, autoformatting

I am using VS2010.

Auto formatting upon using '}' has been extremely useful for me, however recently it's been quite a pain while I've been working on a library.

If i use the line:

```
public Single ExampleProperty { get; set; }
```

It auto formats to:

```
public Single ExampleProperty
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

How can i stop this from happening? I don't want to disable auto-formatting, i just want to enable something like 'allow properties to be defined on a single line' or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Wrapping -> Leave block on single line

This should be what you are looking for

Comment: Too fast an answer for stack overflow ;) Thanks! I'll accept the answer in 4 minutes (as soon as i can).

Comment: looks like you posted just a couple of seconds before me. No problem i will remove my answer, coz there is only one way to solve this problem :) Cheers